# How do I limit user input to specific integers, and keep track of exceptions, in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation

EDIT: The suggested duplicate is incredibly helpful in regards to basic input validation. While it does cover a lot, my specific problem (failing to assign `int(evaluation)` to a variable) is only explicitly addressed here. I'm marking this separately in case anyone else has made a similarly silly mistake :)

I've spent the last few weeks playing with Python 2.7 and having a lot of fun. To learn more about `while` loops, I've created a small script which asks the user for an integer between 1 and 10.

My goal is to then be able to respond to cases in which the user responds with unexpected input, like a non-integer, or an integer outside the specified range. I've been able to fix a lot of my issues with help from other StackOverflow threads, but now I'm stumped.

First, I created a variable, `idiocy`, to keep track of exceptions. (The script is supposed to be sassy, but until I get it working,  *I'm*  the one it's making fun of.)

```
idiocy = 0

while 1:
    evaluation = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        int(evaluation)
        if evaluation < 1 or evaluation > 10:
            raise AssertionError
    except ValueError:
        idiocy += 1
        print "\nEnter an INTEGER, dirtbag.\n"
    except AssertionError:
        idiocy += 1
        print "\nI said between 1 and 10, moron.\n"
    else:
        if idiocy == 0:
            print "\nOkay, processing..."
        else:
            print "\nDid we finally figure out how to follow instructions?"
            print "Okay, processing..."
        break
```

As you can see, I'm trying to handle two different errors -- a `ValueError` for the input type, and an `AssertionError` for the integer range -- and keep track of how many times they're raised. (Really, I only care about knowing whether or not they've been raised at least once; that's all I need to insult the user.)

Anyways, when I run the script in its current form, the error response works just fine ('dirtbag' for non-integers, 'moron' for out-of-range). The problem is that even when I input a valid integer, I still get an out-of-range `AssertionError`.

I suspect that my issue has to do with my `while` logic, but I'm not sure what to do. I've added a `break` here or there but that doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions or blatant errors? Again, total Python beginner here, so I'm half winging it.

//If anyone has simpler, cleaner, or prettier ways to do this, feel free to let me know too. I'm here to learn!

Comment: I would stop working with python 2.7 and focus on python 3, preferably version 3.6.2 if you can. The end of life for 2.7 is only a couple of years away and it would be good if you started out on the right foot without having to relearn some of the finer points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @MatthewPurdon I've been learning with the help of Zed Shaw's infamously divisive book, which only addresses 2.7, since I like its format. That being said, I've thought about moving to 3.x before. I'll look around, but are there any [updated] e-books or websites you'd recommend I get started with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `int(evalutation)`, but you're not assigning it to anything.

Try

```
try:
    evaluation = int(evaluation)
    assert 0 < evaluation < 10
except ValueError:
    ...
except AssertionError:
```

Comment: That's the ticket. Seems obvious in retrospect! Thank you.

Comment: One more thing -- is it bad form to assign `int(evaluation)` to `evaluation`, instead of using a unique variable name? Seems like it could be confusing, unless I've missed something.

Comment: It's a little more verbose, but there's nothing actually wrong with it. If you'd like to cut down on the renaming, you could also have
`try: 
    evaluation = int(raw_input('> ')
except ValueError:
    ...` but in my opinion, this gets a little busy for one line :)

Comment: Ah, my issue was more along the lines of, might it be confusing to write `evaluation = int(evaluation)` instead of, say, `fixed_evaluation = int(evaluation)`? Or does doing it your way overwrite the `raw_input` that `evaluation` was assigned to earlier?

Comment: I see! There's no issue with re-assigning the `evaluation` variable if it's always your intention to convert it to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're not saving the `int` version of `evaluation` to `evaluation` like this:

```
idiocy = 0

while 1:
    evaluation = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        evaluation = int(evaluation) <--- here
        if evaluation < 1 or evaluation > 10:
            raise AssertionError
    except ValueError:
        idiocy += 1
        print "\nEnter an INTEGER, dirtbag.\n"
    except AssertionError:
        idiocy += 1
        print "\nI said between 1 and 10, moron.\n"
    else:
        if idiocy == 0:
            print "\nDid we finally figure out how to follow instructions?"
            print "Okay, processing..."
        else:
            print "\nOkay, processing..."
```

If you wanted to track the types of exceptions raised, you could use `collections.Counter` for `idiocy` and change the code like this:

```
from collections import Counter

idiocy = Counter()

while 1:
    evaluation = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        evaluation = int(evaluation)
        if evaluation < 1 or evaluation > 10:
            raise AssertionError
    except ValueError as e:
        idiocy[e.__class__] += 1 
        print "\nEnter an INTEGER, dirtbag.\n"
    except AssertionError as e:
        idiocy[e.__class__] += 1
        print "\nI said between 1 and 10, moron.\n"
    else:
        if idiocy == 0:
            print "\nDid we finally figure out how to follow instructions?"
            print "Okay, processing..."
        else:
            print "\nOkay, processing..."

>>> idiocy
Counter({AssertionError: 2, ValueError: 3})
```

And you can access the error counts by key like `idiocy[AssertionError]`

Comment: I hadn't seen the `Counter` module before, thank you for sharing. I think I'm better off without it in this script but it'll definitely be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your range test can be refactored as

```
assert 1 <= evaluation <= 10
```

You could keep your insults in a dictionary

```
insults = {AssertionError : "\nI said between 1 and 10, moron.\n",
           ValueError : "\nEnter an INTEGER, dirtbag.\n"
           }
```

And write the try/except like this

```
try:
    ...
except (AssertionError, ValueError) as e:
    print(insults[type(e)])
```

When you change the user input to an int, you need to assign it to something

```
evaluation = int(evaluation)
```

---

[assert](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) was meant for debugging - you are using it incorrectly.

- You should use [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) for non-integer repsonses - the type is wrong.
- You use [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) for responses outside of a range - the value is wrong

Comment: Your last point was especially helpful, thank you. Changing the error types makes the logic much cleaner -- I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0):

In your code: 
`int(evaluation)` is not typecasting evaluation variable to int type. The output is:

```
> 2
<type 'str'>
I said between 1 and 10, moron.
```

Try this:

```
idiocy = 0

while 1:
    try:
        evaluation = int(raw_input("> "))
        if evaluation < 1 or evaluation > 10:
            raise AssertionError
    except ValueError:
        idiocy += 1
        print "\nEnter an INTEGER, dirtbag.\n"
    except AssertionError:
        idiocy += 1
        print "\nI said between 1 and 10, moron.\n"
    else:
        if idiocy == 0:
            print "\nOkay, processing..."
        else:
            print "\nDid we finally figure out how to follow instructions?"
            print "Okay, processing..."
        break
```

By the way you can use tuple to store all your exceptions.
Example:

```
idiocy = 0

all_exceptions = (ValueError, AssertionError)
while 1:
    try:
        evaluation = int(raw_input("> "))
        if evaluation < 1 or evaluation > 10:
            raise AssertionError("\nI said between 1 and 10, moron.\n")
    except all_exceptions as e:
        idiocy += 1
        print str(e)
    else:
        if idiocy == 0:
            print "\nOkay, processing..."
        else:
            print "\nDid we finally figure out how to follow instructions?"
            print "Okay, processing..."
        break
```

Hope it helps.